# OpenMP does not use all threads / Clion / Windows

Tags: multithreading, openmp, clion

learning the first steps with openMP and got stuck a little bit. Why my code does not use all allowable threads? OMP_NUM_THREADS=6 has been set as environmental variable.

```
#include <omp.h>

   int max = omp_get_max_threads();
    std::cout<<"Max threads: "<<max<<std::endl;

#pragma omp parallel
    {
        int n = omp_get_num_threads();
        int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        std::cout<<"There are threads:"<<n<<"Hello from thread: "<<tid<<std::endl;
    };

/*end of parallel section */
    std::cout<<"Hello from the master thread\n";
```

Output:

```
Max threads: 6   
There are threads:1 Hello from thread: 0   
Hello from the master thread
```

Update: I also tried omp_set_dynamic(0); with no success.

Update: it was solved with compilator flag:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /openmp")
```

Comment: Please include the whole file and show what headers you are using. When I ran your code locally I got the expected output.

Also, I believe you're asking about OPENMP, not Open MPI.

Comment: Thanks. The only header #include <omp.h>, edited. Yes, you are right, Open MP, insane that these are two different things. I am sure that code is ok, but whats wrong then? Clion?

Comment: Accidently solved myself, updated in the post.

Comment: @ragnarrok, You should post your solution an answer. It's completely fine to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

It was problem with the compilator/cmakelists.txt, I needed to set this flag:

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /openmp")